# Cannot perform echo command to load driver for rtc module

Tags: i2c, rtc, ds1307

I've come across a few tutorials for adding an rtc module to a pi. They all include a step in which you do `echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device`. When I try this, I get a `bash: ... Permission denied`. If I pipe into a tee command to write to `/sys/class...`, I get `tee: ... invalid argument`. If I try `bash -c` or `sh -c` before putting the echo command in quotes, I get an `Invalid argument` error or `sh: echo: I/O error`. I always run `sudo modprobe` commands beforehand, to `i2c-bcm2708` and `rtc-ds1307`.

I'll note that my rtc device is listed as ds3231, not ds1307, but modprobe on ds1307 is the one that works, so I am confused on that point as well.

What's my next step.

Some pi details: I am using a model b with 512 mb of ram. The OS is Raspbian.

Comment: try adding sudo to the front sudo echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device. If that does not solve the problem we will need a little more information: which model Pi are you using? What OS and version are you using? Note: please add these details to your question not  the comments.

Comment: `sudo echo` also does not work

Comment: instead of echoing the text to the file open it with an editor (create it if necessary) and add the text. Also, see my previous comment re: additional info.

Comment: well, first of all, it was root-only write permissions on that file, and nothing else, so I had to change that. When I was able to open the file and added the appropriate text, I got an `invalid argument` error. and that's with nano.  If I try to open the file with a graphical text editor, I get an i/o error.

Comment: what is the ls -la output for the directory where the file is, and what exactly did you enter in the file?

Comment: the permissions for /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1 are 777 for user and group root, altho with a l and not a d before the r/w/x permissions

Comment: and what are the current permissions on the file itself? What are the files contents.

Comment: Which version of Raspbian  are you using? If it is the latest one, you shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: after  a reboot, the permissions on the `new_device` file are again user-only write-only for root user. Looks like my raspbian is up to date. Kernel is at 4.1.**

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your original

```
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

command is that only root can write to the /sys/class.. file. Normally prefixing a command with `sudo` will give you root privileges, but because of the way that the command is interpreted, the `echo ds1307 0x68` will be run as root, but not the `>` part which writes to the /sys/class... file. To run the whole command as root, you can do:

```
sudo bash
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

This will put you into a root shell, and run the whole command as root. Note that you will be running as user root until you `exit` from the shell.

You can alternately do:

```
echo 'ds1307 0x68' | sudo tee /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

The reason you are not seeing your permission changes stick (in the comments), is that the file is on a sysfs virtual file system, which is re-created each time you boot.

See here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna

See here for more info on sysfs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's a shame that the OP didn't follow up.

Comment: Another possibility: `echo 'ds1307 0x68' | sudo dd of=/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, and it seems to stem from the device already being in use/busy.  If you run `i2cdetect -y 1` and see the device showing `UU` in the output, it is already in use.  When in use, you will get an I/O error trying to add it as a new device.  Try rebooting and then running the command again.  If it has been correctly added, a device at `/dev/rtc0` should also show up.

When actually running the command, I have had the most success from a root terminal. Enter `sudo bash`, then type the `echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device` without any sudo or other modifiers. For this `bash -c` should work as well.

The use of ds1307 is correct for the ds3231, they are designed to be compatible in terms of communication protocol.

Comment: Even without active scripts, if I reboot with the rtc module connected, `i2cdetect` will show a UU in spot 68. However, if I connect the module once the os is running, I do not see a `UU`. However, I get all the same errors on all the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I used this info in writing my guide to getting a Raspberry Pi to work with a DS3231 rtc and Ubuntu.  Posting here so that anyone else can benefit the same way I have benefited.

HOW TO INSTALL AND CONFIGURE AN RTC TO WORK WITH A RASBERRY PI AND UBUNTU.

PURPOSE:

The purpose of this guide is to configure an RTC clock to work with Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi.    Without an RTC when your PI has been off a long time the system time will not update until it connects to the internet.   The system can then encounter errors until the ntp service synchronises with an NTP server on the internet.
The synchronization process can take a long time if the difference between your system time and the actual time is significant, as NTP doesn’t sync instantly it does it incrementally.  Adding an RTC allows the system time to sync from it as well and stay very close to the actual time avoiding any errors.
This is useful if your project needs accurate time between reboots etc.. I started on this as I am building an NTP server as part of my cluster build.

STAGE 1 – PRE-REQUISITES:

A – A Raspberry Pi 4  (mine was an 8gb) This should work on other variants.
C – An RTC clock DS1307 or DS3321 (I used a DS3321) with a working battery.
B – A working wired or wireless network interface
See instructions and where to put it for a working yaml file to get wlan0 connected
C – An up to date Ubuntu Server Installation
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
D – Your keyboard correctly set, you will be editing files
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
E – The I2C interface should be enabled
Boot your Pi with Raspbian run Raspbian config and enable it from there.
F – SSH server installed (it was by default for me but can be installed with the following command)
Sudo apt-get install openssh-server

STAGE 2 – INSTALL I2C TOOLS:
Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A – installs the tools:
sudo-apt get install i2c-tools
B – Check they are running
sudo i2c-detect -y 1
NOTE: By default most clocks are registered at 0x68 if yours is different note it down and replace 0x68 with yours wherever it is mentioned in the guide.

STAGE 3 – CHECK THE DS1307 DRIVERS ARE INSTALLED

Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A - sudo modprobe rtc-ds1307
This should execute without any errors and checks to see if the module loads.  Later in the guide we will get them to load automatically on boot.

STAGE 4 – CHECK THAT YOU CAN CREATE THE NEW RTC INTERFACE:
Note: in Ubuntu this is added as part of new_device, this was a major headache for me as below the command needed to be run under root privileges in bash because the > redirection needs to be interpreted correctly.    After much research I came across a method others had used for similar tasks and it enabled me to get this working at boot time later in the guide.
Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A – switch to bash running as root:
sudo bash
B – This command allows hwclock to access the RTC
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
C – Exit Bash
exit
D – Test that hwclock can now access the RTC
Sudo hwclock   -r
E – Check the system time (if you are connected to the internet this should be correct)
Date
F – Now write the system time to the RTC
Hwclock -w
Note: later in the guide hwclock -s will be used to set the system time from the RTC
STAGE 5 – GET THE RTC-DS1307 MODULE TO LOAD AT BOOT TIME
Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A – Navigate to the following directory:
cd /etc/modules-load.d
C – Edit the modules.conf file
sudo nano modules.conf
D – Add the following line to your modules.conf
#This loads the rtc-1307 module
rtc-1307
STAGE 6 – CREATE A SYSTEMD SCRIPT TO CREATE THE INTERFACE AT BOOT UP AND SYNC THE
SYSTEM TIME WITH THE RTC
Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A – Navigate to the following:
cd /etc/
B – Create the file rtc which will be used as the startup script
sudo nano rtc
C – In Nano add the following lines:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   #this is the script to be executed at boot to create the rtc interface
   echo 'ds1307 0x68' | sudo tee /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
   sudo hwclock -s
```

D -  Quit Nano
ctrl x to save and quit nano
E -  Set the correct file permissions and make the rc script executable.
sudo chmod 755 rtc
sudo chmod +x rtc   (this shouldn’t be necessary but I did it anyway)

STAGE 7 – CREATE THE SYSTEMD FILE:

Execute the following commands at the terminal:

A - Navigate to following directory.
cd /etc/systemd/system/

B – Create the rtc.service file
sudo nano rtc.service
C -  Add the following lines to rtc.service file:

```
   #this calls the rtc script at boot to create the rtc interface new_device
   [Unit]
   Description=RTC Clock
   Before=cloud-init-local.service
   Requires=systemd-modules-load.service
   After=systemd-modules-load.service
   [Type]
   Type=oneshot
   [Service]
   ExecStart=/etc/rtc
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

D – Close and exit Nano
Ctrl + x to exit and save

```
    NOTE: I looked in the /etc/system/system/ folder for a service that I wanted this to run 
    before, my thinking was that I wanted this all up and running before the network started 
    so that any possible issues with time and services that rely on the network wouldn’t be 
    a problem.  I chose the cloud-init-local.service, it is well worth reading up on systemd.
```

E -  Check to see if the rtc.service loads without error:

```
   sudo systemctl start rtc.service   
   Note:  this should start the service if there are errors check the formatting and   
   capitalisation of the file to match above.
```

F – Enable the rtc.service

```
   sudo systemctl enable rtc.service

   Note:  This should output something like:
   Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rtc.service → 
   /etc/systemd/system/rtc.service.
```

Note: If that is successful, you should now have a working RTC and a service that starts it at reboot and syncs the system time to the rtc clock.

STAGE 8 – FINAL TESTS

Execute the following commands at the terminal:
A – reboot the server
reboot now

B – When the server has rebooted logon and issue the following command:
Sudo hwclock -r

```
  Note:  This should return the time as hwclock now has access to the RTC module and 
             the system time is set from the clock on reboot every time.
             configured on reboot.



                                                 FINISH
```